# How to prove that $e^{ax}$ is convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

How to prove that $e^{ax}$ is convex for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Can I prove this without using derivatives? Maybe Taylor Series?

Comment: Isn't enough to show that the derivative is monotonic?

Comment: @ares That by definition involves derivatives, doesn't it?

Comment: @OP I doubt using Taylors series is "alright" if you want to avoid derivatives. They are, by and large, a generalization (encoding the derivatives pretty heavily).

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, of-course, my bad. But I saw the Taylor series and I forgot that.

Comment: Then you may want to use the definition of a convex function. i.e. $f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \leq \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @ares if I use the definition, would $f(y) = e^{ay}$?

Comment: @mgani yes, that's your $f$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality we get $$e^{a\tfrac{u+v}{2}}=\sqrt{e^{au}e^{av}}\le\frac{e^{au}+e^{av}}{2}.$$

This is Jensen inequality. Continuity concludes the proof.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you reach this step by step?

Comment: First try to prove AM-GM inequality: if $a,b>0$, then $\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}{2}.$ Hint: use the square of a difference formula.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I wasn't clear. My actual doubt is: does u and v correspond to x and y from the convex definition? Since n=2?

Comment: Don't pay attention to the concrete letters. $u,v$ are as good as $x,y$ or $\xi,\eta$ and so on. Try to understand what the definition tells us. It tells us that the value of the convex function on a convex combination of arguments is not greater than the convex combination of values.

Comment: @szw1710 The passage from $e^{a\frac{u+v}{2}}=\sqrt{e^{au}e^{av}}\le\frac{e^{au}+e^{av}}{2}$ to $e^{a(tu+(1-t)v)} \le te^{au}+(1-t)e^{av}$ is not clear.